# How to have local storage save variable in new tab in chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Flask application where users can message each other. At the moment I'm trying to have the display name which I've set in one tab be remembered in other tabs I have open.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('name'))
  var username = prompt('What is your Display Name');
  localStorage.setItem('name',username);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#name').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Flack '+ 
localStorage.getItem('name') + '!';
```

So when I first boot up the application on the first tab, the user sets their name through a prompt box, and they're greeted with a "Welcome User123!" message on the page, when I open a new tab however it will say "Welcome undefined!," rather than username I had set in the original tab. How could I make sure that the new tab remembers the original name I had set in the first tab? The javascript code above is what I've currently tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your code:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
    var username = prompt('What is your Display Name');
}

localStorage.setItem('name',username);
```

So if If block is not executed, username is always undefined. To fix the issue, just add `{}`

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
    var username = prompt('What is your Display Name');
    localStorage.setItem('name',username);
}
```